# How To Run Postgres locally

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask

I read the Postgres docs for Flask

and they said that to run Postgres you should have the following code

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = postgresql://localhost/[YOUR_DB_NAME]' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

How do I know my database name?

I wrote db as the name - but I got an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL:  database "[db]" 
does not exist
```

Running Heroku with Flask if that helps

Comment: I actually don't know what I am doing - this is my first time. I tried creating a database, with createdb db but I got the following error - could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Comment: So I don't think I ever created one because I got an error. What should I do/ how should I create one since - createdb db - does not work for me?

Comment: @camus: [There is no such thing as "postgre".](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : Can you help? Do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: P.S. Postgre is a cool name it stands for Post Gangsta Rap Extreme

Comment: @RohitRayudu: Sorry, no clue about Flask. To get started you should go with the tools (and documentation) of your distribution. Or start by reading the PostgreSQL manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-createdb.html).

Comment: Ok. No Problem. I have read the manual - but I still get errors. Thanks though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First step, is to get Flask + Postgresql running locally, and the first step to do *that* is to [install postgresql on your machine](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides).  Next, you should install the [python drivers for postgresql](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/).

For Windows, you can use the [windows installer for postgresql](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgresql-overview) and the [windows installer for the python drivers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Once you have finished the above two steps, you need to [create a database](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/).

For Windows, you can use the bundled pgadminIII tool. Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wvDVBjNDys) that shows how to do just that.

For example, here is how you create a database called `the_database`, and create a user called `databaseuser` with a password `P@ssw0rd` using the built-in tool `psql`:

```
$ psql -d template1 -U postgres
template1=# CREATE USER databaseuser WITH PASSWORD 'P@ssw0rd';
template1=# CREATE DATABASE the_database;
template1=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE the_database to databaseuser;
template1=# \q
```

Here is how you would configure your application with the above information:

```
db_conn = 'postgresql+psycopg2://databaseuser:P@ssw0rd@localhost/the_database' 
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_conn
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: Thank you, Monsieur Khalid - I was having issues with Postgres - finally got it to work - on the 8th attempt at installing it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience with Heroku, but from your messages I would say you don't have PostgreSQL running and you dont have a database at all. Looks like here they have some info https://postgres.heroku.com/ :)

But in your topic you asking about localhost PostgreSQL... So if you want to run your setup locally, first thing to check is if you have PostgreSQL installed and running. If you do, try to connect to it with pgAdmin or from console and create database. If you can't connect - check config for ports, hosts PostgreSQL is listening.

Anyway those messages I see you posted in question in comments, gives me only the idea that you don't have DB created or even running (or you have wrong config).